# Tried to log in application with multiple users from the Excel sheet data provider. But No class found an error getting

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, testng-dataprovider

[image]

The Selenium Webdriver, TestNG version & used libraries are given below.

Selenium version : selenium-server-standalone-3.41.59.jar
TestNG version : 7.4.0

Tried to login with Excel sheet data provider.But no class found error getting.
Added Apache POI excel related dependenices
Added Libraries(Please see the screenshot)
Here is my code.
The Selenium Webdriver, TestNG version & used libraries are given below.
Selenium version : selenium-server-standalone-3.41.59.jar TestNG version : 7.4.0

```
package ui;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class MultiUserLogin {

    public static  WebDriver driver;
    public  WebDriverWait wait;

    String appURL1 = "https://www.google.com";
    

    @BeforeClass
    public void testSetup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:/Geckdriver/geckodriver.exe");
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    }
    

    @Test(dataProvider="LoginData")
    public void VerifyValidLogin(String Username, String Password,String Company) {
        driver.navigate().to(appURL1);
         driver.findElement(By.id("userId")).sendKeys(Username);
            driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(Password);
            driver.findElement(By.id("company")).sendKeys(Company);
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click();
        
                }
    
    @DataProvider(name="LoginData")
    public Object[][] LoginData() throws Exception {
        Object[][] testObjArray = ExcelUtils.getTableArray("E:\\TestNG\\TestData\\TestData.xlsx","Sheet1");
        return (testObjArray);
        }
}




package ui;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelUtils {


    private static XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet;

    private static XSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook;

    private static XSSFCell Cell;

    private static XSSFRow Row;

public static Object[][] getTableArray(String FilePath, String SheetName) throws Exception {   

   String[][] tabArray = null;

   try {

       FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(FilePath);

       // Access the required test data sheet

       ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);

       ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);

       int startRow = 1;

       int startCol = 1;

       int ci,cj;

       int totalRows = ExcelWSheet.getLastRowNum();

       //  function as well to get Column count

       int totalCols = 2;

       tabArray=new String[totalRows][totalCols];

       ci=0;

       for (int i=startRow;i<=totalRows;i++, ci++) {               

          cj=0;

           for (int j=startCol;j<=totalCols;j++, cj++){

               tabArray[ci][cj]=getCellData(i,j);

               System.out.println(tabArray[ci][cj]);  

                }

            }

        }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e){

        System.out.println("Could not read the Excel sheet");

        e.printStackTrace();

        }

    catch (IOException e){

        System.out.println("Could not read the Excel sheet");

        e.printStackTrace();

        }

    return(tabArray);

    }

public static String getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum) throws Exception {

    try{

        Cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);

        CellType dataType= Cell.getCellType();

        if  (dataType == CellType.STRING) {
            
            return "";

        }else{

            String CellData = Cell.getStringCellValue();

            return CellData;

        }
    }catch (Exception e){

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        throw (e);

        }

    
}
}
```

Comment: Added Libraries-logdj-1.2.14 jar, 
logdj2acml.jar,
logdj-api-2.18.0.jar,
logdj-sif4j-impl-2.0-betad.jar,
poi-5.2.3.jar ,
poi-examples-5.2.3.jar,
poi-excelant-5.2.3.jar,
poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar,
poi-ooxml-full-5.2.3jar, 
poi-scratchpad-5.2.3.jar